# how can i add a lot of children without freeze the app xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

in the view page - xaml code

```
 <ScrollView>
          <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="SL">
                    
          </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

code behind

```
  public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitAsync();
       
      
    }

  private async void InitAsync()
  {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);

            });

            btn5.Text = "Task 1 Done";
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            });
            btn6.Text = "Task 2 Done";


            Button[] btn1 = new Button[2000];
          
            for(int i=0; i< btn1.Length; i++)
            {
                btn1[i] = new Button();
                btn1[i].HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill;
                btn1[i].HeightRequest = 50;
                btn1[i].Text = i.ToString();

                SL.Children.Add(btn1[i]);

            }


  }
```

now the problem is that the app freez until the for loop add all buttons,
how can i let the app not freez when this loop working? thank you.

Comment: I'm going to ask the question why do you want to add 2000 buttons to the UI? :)

Comment: its tickets , and every ticket have an id number , when u click on the button that have the id number of the ticket , will open a new page that have all information about that ticket,

Comment: i just want to know , what is the best way to add lot of controlls children , without freeze the UI?

Comment: You should look at using a ‘CollectionView’ as this will allow you to present a large number while optimising and only rendering what needs to be on screen. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/

Comment: why are you not using `ListView` @KhalidOsama

Comment: if i used ListView or CollectionView ,  the problem will solved ?! i think if i add same number of data like 2000 record ,it will have the same problem freezing the UI !

Comment: The key to using something like `CollectionView` is to separate view from your business logic. Look up MVVM and you should find an example of how to achieve it with a CollectionView, this will allow you to bind 2000 items to the CollectionView on screen and it will handle how many to render and you shouldn't see any freeze

Comment: now i have another little problem , when i use list and create the ItemTemplate and cell, i want the buttons color red when data = 1 , and green when data = 2 , and yellow when data = 3 how can i do it ?

DataTemplate ItemTemplate = news DataTemplate(() => { //how can i do if conditions to select the color that i want if violation = 1 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , it will not freeze your UI

Xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button Text="Add Data" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
    <ListView x:Name="myListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <ViewCell>
                     <Button Text="{Binding .}"/>
                 </ViewCell>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Code Behind

```
private ObservableCollection<string> longList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> LongList { get => longList; set { longList = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LongList)); } }
...
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            LongList.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            myListView.ItemsSource = LongList;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: now i have another little problem , when i use list and create the ItemTemplate and cell, i want the buttons color red when data = 1 , and green when data = 2 , and yellow when data = 3 how can i do it ?

DataTemplate ItemTemplate = news DataTemplate(() => { //how can i do if conditions to select the color that i want if violation = 1 }

Comment: you can do data triggers or converters

Comment: sorry, can u give me a small example code please? thank you.

Comment: same issue , i need the solution please?

DataTemplate ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
                        {
 Label birthdayLabel = new Label();
                            birthdayLabel.FontSize = 10;
                            if()
                                birthdayLabel.TextColor = Color.Red;
                            else
                            {
                                birthdayLabel.TextColor = Color.Yellow;
                            }
}
   ListView1.ItemTemplate = ItemTemplate;


how its work in this issue ?!

Comment: post another question, simplify your use case.